# How do I post to another website with a SAML assertion in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, saml

I have a SAML token formatted like so:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_341bea3b-f497-4a4f-adff-2bd65e44fd67" Issuer="http://127.0.0.1:81/" IssueInstant="2012-03-12T15:08:26.618Z">
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2012-03-12T15:08:26.585Z" NotOnOrAfter="2012-04-23T07:08:26.585Z">
    <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
        <saml:Audience>http://127.0.0.2:83/</saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
</saml:Conditions>
<saml:AttributeStatement>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
        </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Attribute AttributeName="name" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
        <saml:AttributeValue>tempName</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#_341bea3b-f497-4a4f-adff-2bd65e44fd67">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>4dssZKnMKbLVftPXnSxZlDjrKnDtyQ8Sb7FRup6wkwE=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
REkPevPfjE86v+SCxGiomP2CConIVjTxuUpCIFDc+sAWUtEq3cMYZDwYfGKgEaSboIv1SUfYl8dUAEhQ+CjlCg7p3jF38f64HxexWHuLty2K+us74OmvK2F8CtG+xgwURAtJ14a6j/dTzuqzpn3hhHI7EXmrW1C5vrSAMQrVcyk=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>
    MIICeDCCAeGgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBgDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxDzANBgNVBAgTBkxvbmRvbjERMA8GA1UEBxMIVmljdG9yaWExITAfBgNVBAoTGFRob21zb25zIE9ubGluZSBCZW5lZml0czEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFDASBgNVBAMTC1Rlc3RpbmdDZXJ0MCAXDTExMDkxOTAwMDAwMFoYDzQwMDAwNzE5MTgwMzMzWjCBgDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxDzANBgNVBAgTBkxvbmRvbjERMA8GA1UEBxMIVmljdG9yaWExITAfBgNVBAoTGFRob21zb25zIE9ubGluZSBCZW5lZml0czEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFDASBgNVBAMTC1Rlc3RpbmdDZXJ0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC16AgeosO1rNdNU1nzAODZTcRuhoew3wJdVAbIcYqU57MLAYIhGIU/tovSGEOHnKjzNciYmXwLV6dVSCuygoOADNMAAgsfWYHDk2iZZLM8XuM2N6VVtJk/pc4wEITxBHLMqeCrJXTN/6JvTB1AHZWmfFm8jqMuMpXlowNEGoMJQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBAExdjee3nfJ5wFtOrQcIwblrrM/XWfzhaj4Zzd6Bc/dofP44/PpMqwdyiJWYf/DmsXTM4YZ2HbdJyWXHCR+m/neWE1diVXlEAuArrjHDFWvsmqqK3bpKzSzabQF4wVxHaxbn49zUqale+tr5gXK36MKwq3I54ohd0T2i7HO8hKhF
    </X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
</saml:Assertion>
```

I want to redirect from a MVC controller to another page in a separate MVC application and pass this SAML token along. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like WIF module does it (and some other STS providers), by sending back a form with hidden input holding the token, and a javascript script that posts the form to the destination.

something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Working...</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="http://emadashi.com/"><input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" />
<input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="your-http-encoded-token-here" />
<noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript>
</form>
<script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you dig into [SignInRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wsfederation.signinrequestmessage_members.aspx) class, and check method WriteFormPost, you will see that it spits such code.

Late for this question, but I hope this helps anyone still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way is to POST that token to the other application and then let it handle it, however you can't actually do a RedirectWithPost() in MVC..

Well you can actually post to the other application with something like new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), but you wouldn't actually be going to the new page but handling the response locally.

How about if you base64encode your XML, and then redirect to the new application via a standard Redirect with your token in the query string ?

```
Redirect(string.Concat(url, "?token=",  Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token))));
```